# Function to return a specific thing from a procedure that are in the same package

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, stored-functions

I have a procedure that calculates the minimum and the maximum number of 2 numbers and I need to write a function that will return the minimum number from the procedure and another function that will return the maximum number from the same procedure. The procedure and the functions are in the same package. I need to call the function, and the function will have to find the requested value inside the procedure. So far, I created the package and the package body, wrote the procedure but I really don't know how to write the functions in order to retrieve the respective values from the procedure. Can anyone help me with this?

```
create or replace package min_max is
   p_min integer;
   p_max integer; 
   function f_min(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer;
   function f_max(n1 in integer,n2 in integer) return integer;
end;

create or replace package body min_max is
  procedure do_all...]
```

I don't know how to get the parameters from the functions to use them in the procedure, 
should I just put the functions signature before defining the procedure?

Comment: Well, at least show us what you wrote, we may be able to help.

Comment: "find the requested value inside the procedure" doesn't really make sense. If the procedure only calculates and uses those internally, as local variables, then there is no way to see them. If the procedure exposes them as OUT variables then just call the procedure. If it sets a global variable then just reference that. There ins't enough information to really help you - showing some code would help, perhaps.

Comment: @AlexPoole using 2 local variables in the package body, the procedure will just modify those 2 variables and the functions will return those variables. I think this is the way

Comment: Local to the procedure, or defined at package level (body or spec)? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60777509/edit) to show a [mcve].

Comment: @AlexPoole added some code

Comment: OK, but that's still not very much... presumably `do_all` is somehow setting `p_min` and `p_max`. What calls that - do the functions need to, or are they to pick up the last-known state, and it's called elsewhere (even though it seems to be private)? What are the function arguments used for?

Comment: @gsalem added some code but stuck to assigning anything to the p_min and p_max variables, it keeps saying that they aren't declared

Comment: @AlexPoole I am thinking to have the procedure modify the p_min and p_max variables and have the functions just return the modified variables, can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am thinking to have the procedure modify the p_min and p_max variables and have the functions just return the modified variables, can I do this?

Sure; though it isn't clear when the procedure should be called. Assuming you need it to be called from outside the package and the functions just return the current state, you would need the specification to include the procedure too:

```
create or replace package min_max is
  p_min integer;
  p_max integer; 
  procedure do_all;
  function f_min(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer;
  function f_max(n1 in integer,n2 in integer) return integer;
end;
/
```

Then have the procedure set the values (here using random numbers, just as a demo); and the functions just return them:

```
create or replace package body min_max is

  procedure do_all is
  begin
    p_min := dbms_random.value(1, 100);
    p_max := dbms_random.value(500, 1000);
  end do_all;

  function f_min(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer is
  begin
    -- do something with n1/n2?
    return p_min;
  end f_min;

  function f_max(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer is
  begin
    -- do something with n1/n2?
    return p_max;
  end f_max;

end min_max;
/
```

Then call the procedure to set the values:

```
begin
  min_max.do_all;
end;
/
```

And call the functions, together or separately:

```
select min_max.f_min(0, 0), min_max.f_max(0, 0) from dual;

MIN_MAX.F_MIN(0,0) MIN_MAX.F_MAX(0,0)
------------------ ------------------
                59                987
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=88aee25a5218a5b89dfe21b515b96a59)

If you need the values from a PL/SQL context, not from a SQL context (i.e. from a query), then as you've declared the variables in the package specification you can refer to them directly, e.g.:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(min_max.p_min);
end;
/
```

> How can I pass the parameters from the functions to the procedure, in order to get the minimum and the maximum values from the functions parameter?

Your procedure needs arguments, and you just pass the values through. If that is all it's used for then the procedure can be private.

```
create or replace package min_max is
  p_min integer;
  p_max integer; 
  function f_min(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer;
  function f_max(n1 in integer,n2 in integer) return integer;
end;
/

create or replace package body min_max is

  procedure do_all (n1 in integer, n2 in integer) is
  begin
    p_min := least(n1, n2);
    p_max := greatest(n1, n2);
  end do_all;

  function f_min(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer is
  begin
    do_all(n1, n2);
    return p_min;
  end f_min;

  function f_max(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer is
  begin
    do_all(n1, n2);
    return p_max;
  end f_max;

end min_max;
/
```

Then:

```
select min_max.f_min(70, 900), min_max.f_max(70, 900) from dual;

MIN_MAX.F_MIN(70,900) MIN_MAX.F_MAX(70,900)
--------------------- ---------------------
                   70                   900

select min_max.f_min(30, 1), min_max.f_max(30, 1) from dual;

MIN_MAX.F_MIN(30,1) MIN_MAX.F_MAX(30,1)
------------------- -------------------
                  1                  30
```

Your variables can also be private (with either version).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=da57a6b304a0a7f54b322418e19f2b73), as above but with variables in the body not the specification so they're private.

But if that is what you're doing then you don't need package variables at all, your procedure could use OUT variables:

```
create or replace package min_max is
  function f_min(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer;
  function f_max(n1 in integer,n2 in integer) return integer;
end;
/

create or replace package body min_max is

  procedure do_all (n1 in integer, n2 in integer, p_min out integer, p_max out integer) is
  begin
    if n2 >= n1 then
      p_min := n1;
      p_max := n2;
    else
      p_max := n1;
      p_min := n2;
    end if;  
    p_min := least(n1, n2);
    p_max := greatest(n1, n2);
  end do_all;

  function f_min(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer is
    l_min integer;
    l_max integer;
  begin
    do_all(n1, n2, l_min, l_max);
    return l_min;
  end f_min;

  function f_max(n1 in integer, n2 in integer) return integer is
    l_min integer;
    l_max integer;
  begin
    do_all(n1, n2, l_min, l_max);
    return l_max;
  end f_max;

end min_max;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=328653c399cedf3b97e04f9545f19e3f)

But then, you don't need this package at all; you can just use the built-in functions directly:

```
select least(70, 900), greatest(70, 900) from dual;

LEAST(70,900) GREATEST(70,900)
------------- ----------------
           70              900

select least(30, 1), greatest(30, 1) from dual;

LEAST(30,1) GREATEST(30,1)
----------- --------------
          1             30
```

but it's an exercise, so...

Comment: This looks nice man, thanks for the effort you put in to help me understand. How can I pass the parameters from the functions to the procedure, in order to get the minimum and the maximum values from the functions parameter?

Comment: Are you trying to get the min/max between the two function parameters? i.e. duplicated what the built-in `least()` and `greatest()` functions already do? If so - why; and what's the point of the global variables?

Comment: Just to practice writing code in plsql. What do I need to do to pass the parameters from the functions so that the procedure can compare them and assign the min and max values to the p_min and p_max variables?

Comment: I think the following may be closer to what the OP is looking for. (I would post as an Answer but the question has been closed, not sure why.) The procedure should have two IN and two OUT parameters. Both functions call the procedure within their execution block; each returns one of the OUT arguments. The point of replicating `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` is just practice - this doesn't sound like a production problem, but a learning problem.

Comment: Yes, I said "if that is what you're doing then you don't need package variables at all, your procedure could use OUT variables". I guess I can add an example but it's already too long... The OP has said it's for practice. And it was closed as I was about to retract my vote after some more info was provided.